# How can I specify the filesystem absolute path in a require_once in PHP?

Tags: php, path, filesystems, root, require-once

Simply put, how do I specify an absolute filesystem path using the require_once keyword in PHP?  The code will be run in CLI, not on a webpage.  What is the root file path?  I am running Windows, FYI.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On windows, it's the backslash notation, also you have to escape them if you are using double quotes.

```
require_once("C:\\folder\\folder\\etc");
```

Answer (score 7):

Try using a [Magic Constant `__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

> `__DIR__`  The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to
>   dirname(`__FILE__`). This directory name does not have a trailing slash
>   unless it is the root directory. (Added in PHP 5.3.0.)

Answer (score 2):

```
require_once('/some/path/foo.php');
```

Starting the path with a `/` indicates you are using a absolute (starting in root) path.

```
require_once('some/path/foo.php');
```

Starting the path without a `/` indicates you are using a absolute (starting in [current working dir](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)) path.

Otherwise, have a look at the __FILE__ and __DIR__ [magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Comment: Whoever downvoted this: at least have the decency to explain *why*

Comment: They certainly should have explained - I am now left wondering if your answer works on Windows, because that would be my assumption as to why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `\` alone will get you the root of the current drive (typically `C:\`), or if you need to you can specify which drive you need. Just remember to escape those backslashes, or use forward slashes instead (Windows will silently convert them)